Reposting part of a youtube video
Let's say someone has a 1 hour video on YouTube then another person takes a small part of this video (60 seconds) and reposts it on YouTube shorts.
Is that copyright infringement?

The TOS between YouTube and the users might matter.

Have you read the "four factors" of fair use? It's not that difficult a concept. This will most likely meet the "amount used" factor, but the other three factors have to be taken into account.

@Barmar If you put up a camera to film how an experiment works and is set up, and someone cuts the one minute where the reaction goes, that would be the crucial part of the video, ripping the heart, and so the amount used could weigh against the reupload.

@Trish True, the wording is actually "amount and substantiality". If the one minute is crucial, it might be too "substantial". I did qualify my comment with "most likely", every case must be viewed on its own.

Not nearly enough information. It depends on what you're copying and what you're doing with it, not just the length of what you're copying (although copying a small portion of a larger whole does work in your favor). It is entirely possible that using 60 seconds of a 1-hour video could be fair use, and also possible that it's infringement. It would probably be infringement to just repost a collection of clips as you found them with no transformative, review, or commentary element, for example, but it might be acceptable to use a clip for educational or review purposes. It's impossible to determine whether or not it's infringement from only the fact that it's 1 minute of a 60-minute video.
